# Disable a dropdown based on Date attribute

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-attribute, date

I have created a 2 date attribute which is Date_from and Date_to via back-end. Admin can add these dates and related time slots in another drop-down attribute which is choose_date. In the frontend, there is a calendar written in phtml. When a user chooses a date, I need to disable and enable the dropdown based on the date_from and date_to attribute values. How to do that.